# I want to count "hours into a month" in php

Tags: php, date, datetime

The following code helps me project data from a database onto our internal adminsite for the current day.

Since we're in multiple time zones, we use UTC time for basic time function, but since our office is in California, we want the date to actually be = `($date)'hours' - 8`, because PST is 8 hours behind.

We use the following logic to show the "previous day" if it's "a day ahead" UTC time but the same day our time, which works great, however, on the last day of the month at 4 PM, all of our data is hidden.

```
<?php 

$date = getDate();

if ($date['hours'] < 8) {
    $dateDay = $date['mday']-1;
} else {
    $dateDay = $date['mday'];
}

$dateMonth = $date['mon'];
// last day of month
// $dateMonth = $date['mon'] - 1;
$dateYear = $date['year'];
$dateTime = $dateYear . "-" . $dateMonth . '-' . $dateDay . ' 08:00:00';
```

So, this 'if' function works great to show the true "day." What it says is, if the UTC hour < 8, then it's actually yesterday, as 3 AM UTC time is actually 7 PM the day before PST.

What I was wondering is if there's a way to track "month hours", so I could use the same 'if' function that reads "if we're less than 8 UTC hours into the month, it's actually still last month."

That way it'll work regardless of whether the month has 28, 30 , or 31 days. Does such logic exist?

Comment: Consider using DateTime objects, which are timezone and daylight savings aware

Comment: Use the DateTime class supplied in core PHP. It has all the functionality you would ever need rather than hand cranking things with whatever you are using

Answer (score 1):

I think its the best way to deal with it :

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('2016-08-08', new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DateTime::sub` or `DateTime::modify` method which will keep correct month for you:

```
$now = new DateTime(getDay()); // supposing getDate() returns something that can be parsed with DateTime constructor

// Unless using DateTimeImmutable, cloning is needed to prevent altering the original object
$min = clone ($now); 
$min->modify('-8 hours');
// alternatively $min->sub(new DateInterval('PT8H'));

if ($now->format('m') !== $min->format('m')) {
    // month differs
}
```